# Unable to deploy applications larger than 64 MB to IBM Application Center

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

Running Worklight 6.2, I'm not able to upload application artifacts to the Application Center if they are larger than 64MB.  I have other instances of Application Center where size is not an issue.  All of my instances are using DB2 as their database.

How do we remove the size limitation for this instance of Application Center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to resolving this issue may lie in how the DB2 transaction log size is configured.  The LOGFILSIZ database configuration parameter can be used to attenuate the maximum transaction size, which is what needs to change to raise the ceiling on the maximum app size uploaded when using DB2.

To change the LOGFILSIZ parameter, visit [This page](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/dev/t_managing_db2_transaction_log_size_app_center.html) in the MobileFirst 7.1 Knowledge Center.

Comment: John, your question is about Worklight 6.2, but you then point to a KC topic for v7.1; is the information missing in the v6.2 KC?